# How to center align the text in UITextView after backspacing the first line?

Tags: ios, uitextview, text-alignment

I want the text centered all the time, but when I backspace all of the text on the first line, the text is no longer centered.
Any solutions for this? please help...

I have uploaded it on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLb7YtzG_e4), please take a look

And this is my setting on UITextView
[image]

p.s. Actually I have tried do it with textView.attributedText, but no luck:(

Answer (score 2):

You can add UITextViewDelegate and implement method:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Comment: thx, it seems a workaround, but the cursor position is still remain at left at the beginning, is it possible to locate it at center as well?